# Embedded ActiveMQ Artemis cluster and HA configuration

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to understand how to configure HA, broadcast group, discovery group and clustering for ActiveMQ Artemis when embedded in a Spring Boot application. This is the configuration I have and the broker runs fine.

I cant find any example of programmatic configuration, always configuring in `broker.xml`.

I'm having trouble configuring BroadcastGroup and DiscoveryGroup. I can't find a way to configure things like group-address/port, connector etc..

My idea was to make this a master and create a slave broker, and two more of pairs like that to create a cluster of 3 master/slave pairs, but I'm stuck with configuring it.

```java
@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop", name = "artemisBroker")
public EmbeddedActiveMQ broker() throws Exception {
    EmbeddedActiveMQ embedded = new EmbeddedActiveMQ();
    
    ConfigurationImpl config = new ConfigurationImpl();
    config.setSecurityEnabled(false);
    config.setClusterUser("admin");
    config.setClusterPassword("admin");
    
    config.addAcceptorConfiguration("artemis", "tcp://localhost:61619");
    config.addConnectorConfiguration("artemis", "tcp://localhost:61619");
    
    SharedStoreMasterPolicyConfiguration haPolicy = new SharedStoreMasterPolicyConfiguration();
    config.setHAPolicyConfiguration(haPolicy);
    
    BroadcastGroupConfiguration broad = new BroadcastGroupConfiguration();
    broad.setName("bg-group1");
    config.addBroadcastGroupConfiguration(broad);

    DiscoveryGroupConfiguration dg = new DiscoveryGroupConfiguration();
    dg.setName("dg-group1");
    config.addDiscoveryGroupConfiguration("dg-group1", dg);

    ClusterConnectionConfiguration cluster = new ClusterConnectionConfiguration();
    cluster.setName("cluster");
    cluster.setConnectorName("artemis");
    cluster.setMessageLoadBalancingType(MessageLoadBalancingType.ON_DEMAND);
    cluster.setMaxHops(1);
    cluster.setDiscoveryGroupName("dg-group1");
    config.addClusterConfiguration(cluster);
    
    embedded.setConfiguration(config);
    
    return embedded;
}
```